# Resource temporarily available while accessing the device over adb

Tags: linux, command-line, embedded, adb

I have been seeing the following messages quite often while I'm trying to access the embedded device over adb.

```
sh: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable
[1]+  Done(1)                    cat /dev/smd7
```

```
cat: read error: Network dropped connection on reset
```

```
/bin/sh: can't create /dev/smd7: No such device
```

After looking a bit online, I see it could be due to the limit on the items listed as follows:

```
-f: file size (blocks)             unlimited
-t: cpu time (seconds)             unlimited
-d: data seg size (kb)             unlimited
-s: stack size (kb)                8192
-c: core file size (blocks)        unlimited
-m: resident set size (kb)         unlimited
-l: locked memory (kb)             16384
-p: processes                      2386
-n: file descriptors               1024
-v: address space (kb)             unlimited
-w: locks                          unlimited
-e: scheduling priority            0
-r: real-time priority             0
```

What I'm not sure if is it really caused by a limit on the processes or anything else? I don't want to try random things without knowing about them but would setting processes to unlimited be a feasible idea?

Comment: Which OS? Can you `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"`?

Comment: it's a linux image for a particular embedded platform.`journalctl --since="-5 minutes"` does output something really long. what do you want see out of it?